# LinkedIn button XMLHttpRequest cannot load

Tags: xmlhttprequest, linkedin-api

I am using the LinkedIn developer button on a live server. I'm getting the following error:
`XMLHttpRequest cannot load` `is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin`.

I understand generally what that problem is. But I wouldn't expect there to be an issue when using something as popular and as big as linkedIn. Am I doing something wrong here or should everyone who uses the linked developer buttons be receiving the same error?

**Update**

I've tried just the basic apply button default code on one of my pages and it works fine. I get no errors. But there is another page I have and it brings up this error. I'm not sure why, surely it either works for my site on a whole or it doesn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue. Hopefully my naivety will save others time. I had an inline javascript statement that referenced 'token'. Something the linkedIn script also used.